# Testing an addUser GraphQL/MongoDB mutation in Cypress

Tags: mongodb, graphql, cypress

I've successfully created a Cypress test that creates a new token and user object. The problem is that, since I've hard coded the arguments accepted by the addUser mutation, the test only runs once. On a second run, the DB returns an error stating that the user already exists. I have a deleteUser mutation as well, but it takes in the userId to do so. The userId is dynamically created by MongoDB, so it will be different each time I run the test. I'm not quite sure how to both test the deleteUser mutation and ensure that the addUser test runs successfully each time. Any suggestions are greatly appreciated!

```
import {
  addUser,
  login,
  allUsers,
  findUserById,
  deleteUser,
} from "../GraphQLBody/Users";

describe("User Queries and Mutations", () => {
  const URL = "http://localhost:3001/graphql";

  it("Creates a new user", () => {
    cy.request({
      url: URL,
      method: "POST",
      body: {
        query: addUser,
      },
    }).then((res) => {
      console.log(res.body);
      expect(res.status).to.eq(200);
      expect(res.body).to.have.property("data");
      expect(res.body.data).to.have.property("addUser");

      const { token, user } = res.body.data.addUser;

      expect(token).to.be.a("string");
      expect(user).to.be.an("object");
      expect(user).to.have.property("name", "Test User");
      expect(user).to.have.property("email", "test.user@gmail.com");
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand - why can't you call `deleteUser` at the end of the test?

Comment: I can call ```deleteUser```, but because the user is created with a new MongoDB "_id" each time, I would have to manually run a ```getAllUsers``` query to get the specific "_id" for the user I wanted to delete. My goal is to build a fully automated testing suite that creates a user and then later deletes that specific user at the end of the test without having to manually find that user's "_id".

Comment: You have `expect(user).to.be.an("object")` - wouldn't that `user` object carry an `id` property?

Comment: Yes, but I'm not sure how to access that to hard code it into a GraphQL mutation.  The ```deleteUser``` mutation is imported in the above code block from another file. It looks like this:

```mutation {
    deleteUser(_id: $id) {
      _id
      name
      email
      password
    }
  }```

So, my question is how can I update this mutation with the id that I just created in the previous it block every time I run the test? 

For example, on the front-end, I queried for the user object using the JWT Auth token kept in local storage. How do I do that in Cypress?